# Vanilla Forums sitemapindex.xml file inaccessible by nginx

Tags: nginx, vanilla-forums

My forum is installed on the url: example.com/forums

I have used nginx and Vanilla to "prettify" the urls. I've set

`/forum/conf/config.php, “RewriteUrls” to “True”.`

and in my nginx.conf:

```
location /forums {
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires 30d;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ @forums;
}

location @forums {
    rewrite ^/forums(.+)$ /forums/index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

The problem is I installed the [sitemap plugin](https://vanillaforums.org/addon/sitemaps-plugin) by Vanilla Forums.

and the resulting sitemap is supposed to be located at

`example.com/forums/sitemapindex.xml`

But when I navigate there nginx gives me a 404.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the URI `/forums/sitemapindex.xml` is being processed by the `location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$` block and not being forwarded to `/forums/index.php`.

If you do not serve static `.xml` files, you could simply remove the `|xml` term from the regular expression.

Otherwise, you will need to make that URI a special case, for example:

```
location = /forums/sitemapindex.xml {
    rewrite ^ /forums/index.php?p=/sitemapindex.xml last;
}
```

Comment: I was incorrectly focused on the rewrite. Thx! This solved it.